# Saving averages in text file

Tags: python, list, average

I am making an average calculator in python, i have to save the averages in a text file and have done it like this:

```
Mean = statistics.mean(aver)
Mode = statistics.mode(aver)
Medi = statistics.median(aver)
file = open("Averages.txt", "a")
file.write("\n\nYour numbers are" + aver +
           "\nMean   : " + Mean +
           "\nMode   : " + Mode +
           "\nMedian : " + Medi)
```

(aver is a list of numbers i am finding the average of)

when i try to run this part of the code, i recieve the error message:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

I tried basic stuff like adding 'str' on but it doesnt help.

Comment: in the `file.write` make it `str(aver)`, does that work?

Answer (score 1):

```
file.write("\n\nYour numbers are" + **aver** +
```

this would be better as something like this:

```
aver = " " + ", ".join(aver) + " "
```

which converts your list to a comma separated string.